# su-exec: setgroups: Operation not permitted - error on Alpine container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, superuser

H,

I'm re-working some container images that have been running the containers as root, which is non-ideal for security. I'm using the [su-exec](https://github.com/ncopa/su-exec) package (available through `apk` [here)](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/main/x86/su-exec) to run a bunch of commands that would require a superuser but are called with a non-root user that makes use of `su-exec`; note that this package is basically `gosu` that takes up less space.

To test out the command out I ran and exec'd into an alpine container with `su-exec` added via `apk` but I can't seem to run anything and continue to get the error

```
su-exec: setgroups: Operation not permitted
```

when simple commands like `apk add <pkg>`  or `sh` are run with the non-root user:

```
$ su-exec root apk add --no-cache curl
su-exec: setgroups: Operation not permitted
$ su-exec root sh
su-exec: setgroups: Operation not permitted
$ su-exec --help
Usage: su-exec user-spec command [args]
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: ever got around to fix it? running into the same problem.